# Generate a division which result hasn't dot and divisor and dividend are generated random from a range of numbers

Tags: java, android, math, random

My problem is mainly a mathematic logic problem, more than a code problem.

I have an android app where I generate a division.

I have to generate a division which divisor  and dividend are generated random from a specific range of number (let's say 10-1000) and which result is a number without dot.

For example:

**A(10-1000) : B (10-1000) = C (number without dot)**

Does anybody know how to reach my goal. Math is not a friend of mine.

Thank you

Comment: When you say a number without a dot, do you just mean an integer? For example, 3 instead of 3.14?

Comment: Yes, the result must be a positive int

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result of a division to be an integer, then you need to start with a multiplication.  If A / B = C, then A = B * C.  Start by picking two random integers ("no dot") B and C.  Find A by multiplying then together.  Ask "What is A / B?" and the answer will be the integer C.

Some pseudocode:

```
B <- 10 + rand(991)  // B in [10..1000]
C <- 10 + rand(991)  // C in [10..1000]
A <- B * C
display("What is " + A + " / " + B + "?")
read(answer)
if (answer == C)
  display ("Correct.  Well done.")
else
  display("Wrong answer.  The correct answer was " + C)
end if
```

Comment: The problem is that A must be a number from 10 to 1000

Comment: Then repeatedly pick BC pairs until A is in the correct range.  B and C could be in the range [2..500] to reduce the number of misses.

Answer (score 0):

The "math" logic here (example values):

> if((2 % 2.5) > 0) aka check if 2 is evenly divisible by 2.5

As long as the example above is false the randomly generated values wont return an integer or "a number without a dot".

```
Random random = new Random();

    int lowerbound = 10;


    long counter = 0;

    while(true){

        double a = random.nextInt(10000-lowerbound)+lowerbound+1;//a number between 10 and 10000
        double b = random.nextInt(10000-lowerbound)+lowerbound+1;//a number between 10 and 10000

        double result = (a/b);

        if( (result % Math.round(result)) == 0){

            System.out.println(a + "/" + b + "=" + result);

            int ires = (int) Math.round(result);

            System.out.println(ires);
            break;
        }

        counter++;
    }
```